# Decompose a combined IntFlag into its individual flags

Tags: python, enums

How can I get the individual flags from a combined [IntFlag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntFlag) value in Python?

```
import enum

class Example(enum.IntFlag):
    A = 0b0001
    B = 0b0010
    C = 0b0100

combined = Example.A | Example.B

# How can I get the individual flags back?
flags = [flag for flag in combined]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A list comprehension could work:

```
flags = [flag for flag in Example if flag in combined]
```

If the bits in your flag values overlap then the above will give you all the possible flags found in the combined value.

I didn't see a public API to do this in Python 3.7's standard library. The `enum` module does have a private `_decompose` function that is a more sophisticated version of the above, and is used in `IntFlag`'s `__repr__` method.

Comment: Nice but looking at the source for [`__contains__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/enum.py#L862-L870) - slow! All those isinstance checks...